# How do I avoid deleting a pointer twice when two classes share the same heap object?

Tags: c++, pointers, destruction

How do I avoid deleting a pointer twice when two classes share the same heap object? I've encountered this kind of problem: two large class objects share one large object. The are initialized in initial function. Because it is large, so I don't want to copy them. I allocate them in the heap and save the pointer:

```
class A {
   public:
     A(C* in_p) : p(in_p){}
     ~A() {delete p;}
   private:
   C* p;
}
class B {
   public:
      B(C* in_p) : p(in_p){}
      ~B(){delete p;}
   private:
   C* p;
}
class C {
    public:
    ~C() {...}
}
void initial(A* pa, B* pb) {
     C* a = new C;
     C* b = a;
     pa = new A(a);
     pb = new B(b);
     ... some other initialization codes
}
int main() {
    A* pa = nullptr;;
    B* pb = nullptr;
    initial(pa, pb);
    ........ some processing codes
    //clear up
    delete pa;
    delete pb;
}
```

But when I clean up them, the problem is after `A`'s destruction, `C` class's instance is not in the heap. Then `B`'s destructor delete the same heap area, and call `C`'s destructor, it crash since there is no `C`'s pointer there and call `C->destructor` will crash.  B doesn't know `C` is already not exist after `A` being deleted, and `B`'s member `(C*)p` will not change when `A` destructs its own `(C*)p`.

I can neither pass `C* p` by reference or pass `C**` to link `A`'s `p` and `B`'s `p`, since after `initial()` finish, the local stack variables `C*(a) C*(b)` will be not there any more. So after `initial()`, `A`'s `(C**)p` and `B`'s `(C**)p` will store the unknown memory address and it will crash when use them.

So what do you handle this situation in C++ user self-managed traditional garbage collection before smart pointer came out?

Comment: `initial` does not take `pa` and `pb` by reference (or `**`) so any assignment to `pa` and `pb` in that function are not reflected outside of `initial`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide a [minimal, complete, and reproducible example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? You are not demonstrating any sharing... `pa` and `pb` own different `C` objects.

Comment: *So what do you handle this situation in C++ userself-managed traditional garbage collection before smart pointer came out?*  Programmers created their own smart pointer class.

Comment: How do you think smart pointers are written? With fairy dust?

Comment: If you have `nullptr` then why not `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: Exactly the same way as the smart pointer does: Proxy object has ownership of the pointer, A and B use the proxy.

Comment: Now I would use a `std::shared_ptr`. Before C++11 I would have used a `boost::shared_ptr`.

Comment: When I got this problem, the only thing I think can work with this is using smart pointer. Then the question came to my mind that how did people do in old days that smart pointer is not supported before C++11. There must be a way to handle this type of problems. And I see, as comments, people can create a smarter pointer class themselves in old days. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::shared_ptr`. If you don't have it, use `boost::shared_ptr`. If you can't use it, write your own based on boost's design. Unless your C++ compiler is decades old I don't see any reason you can't use one of those three options.